# Is there a way to improve gear in structured PvP?

Tags: guild-wars-2

After playing a few games on [structured PvP](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Structured_PvP), I began to wonder if there is any way to improve your PvP gear you receive when you join the [Heart of the mists](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Heart_of_the_mists).

When you get into sPvP you receive a full-set of abilities, trait points and gear, I see you can change the runes from your gear and one acessory, but I don't see any gear progression as your glory rank passes. So, how does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Gear in Structured PvP will always be the same quality. As you increase in Glory you get different-looking armour and weapons, but your equipment will always be on the same level as everyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

Glory rank progression shows how much time you played in PvP. How much experience you have, how well you might fare. And the reward is better looking skins. This seems kinda meh, but this way you can't rely on gear difference to win battles. And at the same time, you won't be beaten to a pulp by a less skilled player having an extra-powerful axe (read, Shadow*kof*mourne). All that matters is skill.